# How can I manage Intent association with Apps?

Tags: applications

When the system emits an Intent for which you have multiple apps that can handle the intent, a dialog opens to tell you which application you want to use with that intent.

Is there a way to see what these associations are, and clear them?

If there is no app or interface to do that, do you know of an API to access these associations?

EDIT: When I said associations, I was thiking of the "late-bound" associations. For example, when I open a link and I have multiple browsers, an intent is fired saying "view link", and I choose "always use that application"; what can I do if, after some time, I would prefer to use another application for that intent?

Comment: The fact that one cannot view all registered Intents is a serious flaw in the AOSP

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it's a no to both those questions. Yes you can clear default associations only if you know which app is associated with with `Intent` (you will still be prompted with the dialog asking you which app you'd like to use with the current `Intent`).

Apart from that there is no way to clear associations. They are hard coded inside each app, there is no way to remove them.

UPDATE: To answer your edited question head to **Settings > Applications > Manage applications** find your application that you chose as your default app for that intent, click **Clear defaults**

Answer (score 5):

You can remove some `Intent` associations by going to the specific app that you specified the `Intent` for in the `Settings` --> `Applications` --> `Manager Applications` --> `[Find your app]` --> `"Clear Defaults"` button.

There is no way to view all associations given from `Intents` to `Apps`

Answer (score 2):

If your device is rooted, you can use apps like [AutoRun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun.pro) (ARM) to list up all registered listeners, and even can disable/enable them at will (e.g. to prevent a certain app from firing up at times you don't want it to). This would correspond to "clearing an association".

Comment: The app you link to only appears to enable and disable *broadcast receivers*, so it won't affect different *activities* that you can choose between.

Comment: I was looking exactly for AutoRun Manager. Thanks!