# How can I free up RAM automatically?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, ram

I'm very tired of seeing my RAM used up by unwanted apps which I don't launch regularly, but they continue to appear in the taskbar. Every time I closed them and free the memory. After I restart my phone I have 200 mb of free RAM but after I start closing apps the free memory decreases. I used a task killer but it works the same way. Is there any way to automatically clear out my RAM periodically?

Comment: Unused RAM is wasted RAM. If you don't experience performance issues you should be happy that Android prefetches the Apps in RAM for fast re-open times. In fact Android tries to be smart about RAM management. See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-i-really-need-to-install-a-task-manager

Comment: @Flow when RAM gets below from 70 mb then I experience the performance issue other wise no problem.

Comment: Low ram does not cause performance issues, CPU cycles cause performance issues. see my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19000/is-there-a-way-to-permanently-turn-off-google-maps-until-needed/19001#19001). Another key question though, do you have at least Android 2.2 (froyo)?

Comment: @RyanConrad i have 2.3 gingerbread.

Comment: Not sure why it was down-voted. It is a good question, because many users will ask themselves this at some stage. Turns out that the answer is "you don't need to worry about this, it is intended and normal", but this alone does not make it a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also: [How can I stop applications and services from running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/30332/1465)

When you free the memory you're just killing the apps using it or that Android has stopped and put in the background.  The only real solution is to not use apps, or to accept that every time you switch apps your position in the old one will be forgotten.  You'd probably need a custom-built ROM that entirely altered the way Android does memory management in order to get around this; having something auto-clear the RAM would end up killing the app you're currently using.  Another alternative is creating a swap partition, though how to do so is a different question.