# Choosing apps to load and remove from memory when using Android

Tags: applications, ram, system

I'm not a programmer. And as far as I know, Android uses as much RAM as possible, loading as many apps as possible, so that launching / opening (or returning to them) is smoother.

**My question is:**

Is there any way to choose which applications I ALWAYS want to keep in memory, and which ones I NEVER want to have there?

**For example:**

WhatsApp is a very common app. I would always want it to be there. Google Maps is always open and occupying space. I barely use it, and I don't mind to waiting 5-10secs until it opens. It would be better to use that RAM for other apps, such as my browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What android version are you referring to?

Comment: I don't recommend trying to come up with a way to outsmart Android's system resource handling. The Android OS handles the closing of specific apps/services very well and to try to manually control this will lead to unexpected results. I highly do not recommend you looking into task killers, etc. The OS will simply restart any service you kill which will waste resources (battery, processing time, etc.).

Comment: Related: [How can I free up RAM automatically?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19243/how-can-i-free-up-ram-automatically) - [0 ram free on ICS](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36828/0-ram-free-on-ics) - [Are there guidelines on how much free RAM a phone should have](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20032/are-there-guidelines-on-how-much-free-ram-a-phone-should-have-specifically-sam)

Answer (score 3):

You can never "*choose*" per-se an app and dictate that the app will have that guaranteed amount of memory.

Sure, Google Maps consume space, but that's for the actual application, does not mean its hogging up memory, Android is pretty smart when it comes to memory management.

When you long press the home key, it shows the recent apps list, **that** does not mean they are all loaded at the same time. Android keeps track of which activities was shown and if necessary load them again, and once the pressure of RAM space hits a certain threshold, Android will boot them out to make room for other apps.

You cannot override Android's dictation of **how** and **what** application should be in RAM, just by a user's presumption that "*this certain app should be there in memory and has guaranteed X amount of RAM, **because I want it to***"

Android is **not** Windows, where their Task Manager is available at all times via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and zap away processes to "free up memory".. That mantra should be firmly repeated ad-nauseum! :)

As Ryan Conrad's statement in the comment, from the discussion arising out of the likes of RAM Boosters, Task Killers et al, this statement sums up exactly why the apps mentioned can have a negative effect on the battery, not to mention introducing instabilities into the system - *It's CPU cycles that you should be more worried about than memory.* **WORD** CPU cycles drains the battery regardless and as the commentator says *Free Memory is wasted Memory. Let the OS handle it. It is better at doing it. It knows what memory can be freed safely without causing additional strain and drain on the device*

Simples really :)

Comment: Yes, but you can say for Android to kill unnecessary applications and services to have (for example) browser working faster.

Comment: Bzzzt!!!! Wrong! You will end up having to *restart services* which slows down and chewing up more battery! Read [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18765/do-task-killers-actually-work) thus negating battery life as a result!

Comment: Free Memory is wasted Memory. Let the OS handle it. It is better at doing it. It knows what memory can be freed safely without causing additional strain and drain on the device. having 100% (or close to) memory in use is not a bad thing. It's CPU cycles that you should be more worried about than memory.

Comment: @RyanConrad exact! I'll quote you on this important last statement!!!! +1 from me! :)

Comment: Sorry, I answered in the "Smart RAM Booster" comment. I'm not used to this forum :)

Answer (score 1):

If your device is **Android 4.0+** and **rooted**, try "Greenify" which I developed.

You can safely hibernate any app you do not want it to run stealthily (thus eat your memory, battery and slow down your device) when you are not actively using it, while still keep it fully functional when you explictly run it, either from launcher or by sharing anything with it.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Smart RAM Booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.rambooster):

> Most of Android devices bundle with limited memory. Android task
> manager will selectively kill low priority tasks in order to reserve
> memory to higher priority task. That’s not always run at an
> appropriate time, causing low responsive apps, lagging, especially
> when you launch a new app after heavily browsing web pages. It causes
> a worse experience.
>
> How RAM Booster works
>
> RAM Booster is designed to overcome these issues
> by selectively kill less important apps that are running in the
> background but consumes considerable device’s memory. RAM Booster
> comes with auto-boost in 4 levels: aggressive, strong, medium, gentle.

Comment: That app looks like a equivalent of Windows *Task Manager*, zap away processes, and this could interfere with Android's own Memory Manager and increase de-stability overall. Cannot help wonder, but the impression I get that this app requires root...

Comment: @t0mm13b Root is not needed...

Comment: I find these apps like battery savers and memory managers tend to take up additional resources and not really improve overall performance

Comment: That's one of the typical "shoot-and-kill" games, as the last quoted paragraph clearly shows: it works by *by selectively kill less important apps*, which is not the job of a task-killer but of the OOM-killer. Besides, most of those "less important apps" will immediately restart either -- so all you gain from it is more battery drain. Very smart. Moreover, as spences10 just wrote, they use up ressources themselves...

Comment: @spences10 I also don't use them - it's just application which OP looking for.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. However, I haven't found yet what I was looking for.

Task-killers APPs, as some people have explained here, just "force" the system to re-open the previous APPs again, draining battery.

The explanation of how good Android manages RAM doesn't helpe neither. As much as it is well designed, there is obvious a lack of control right there. Just for installing an APP it doesn't mean I want it to be in my RAM memory.

As I said, Gmaps is always there, and I barely use it (once a month, aprox).

Would it be difficult to develop an APP for these purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a rooted user just convert your app into system app by using rom tool box pro or any other app then it will not close after you swipe away the app from recent app.and runs in background.If you don't want maps or other pre installed apps to run uninstall them and reinstall from playstore and greenifying them will make your battery last long.

Comment: Give us the link of the app and some detailed steps for better understanding.