# How do you disable system apps in Android 4.x.x (and up)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, bloatware, disable-app, system-apps

I heard you can "freeze" or "disable" system apps starting in Android 4.0 without rooting. How do you do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can disable only System apps from Android 4.0 onwards.

Check the guide [here](http://www.phonebuff.com/2012/03/disable-system-app-android-4-0/) with video.

Basically you have to:

> 1. Go to your phone’s main settings menu.
> 2. Go to the “Apps” or “Applications” option.
> 3. Go to the “All” tab in your list of apps.
> 4. Find the app you wish to disable and tap on it.
> 5. Press the disable button next to the force stop button.
> 6. If the disable button isn’t
>      visible, you have to press “uninstall updates” first. Then go back
>      to step 5

To enable it again:

> Once you’ve disabled the app, it will be hidden from your phone as if
>   it were never there. The great news is if you ever wanted it back, all
>   you have to do is the same process but “enable” it instead. Just to
>   let you know, disabled apps show up at the very bottom of the app list
>   (not in alphabetical order) if you ever wish to re-enable it.

**Update:**

To disable user installed apps I use this aswesome software called [Titanium backup pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) (needs root). Freezing app i.e. disabling app is only one of its many features.

To freeze one app:

1. Open Titanium backup pro
2. Go to Backup and Restore tab
3. Find you app and click it
4. Choose freeze from the menu
5. To restore click defrost instead of freeze

Note: Freezing app still consumes space.

I personally use this to freeze heavy app like Skype. Application settings like username and password aren't lost in this way.

Comment: Oh ok, I was already aware of this... So there's no way to disable installed apps? I'd like to prevent certain apps from running, but not uninstall them.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: @trusktr That's what the disable apps function does.

Comment: @roxan: OP specifically asked for a non-rooting solution.

Comment: Hehe, yeah. I was looking for a non-root solution... I may figure out how to root my phone manually sometime. :D

Comment: Is this technically the same as the `pm` terminal command?

Comment: @NoBugs I've mentioned the difference here: [Is "Disabling" apps with Android 4 similar to "Freezing" in Titanium backup?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/122643)