# Is "Disabling" apps with Android 4 similar to "Freezing" in Titanium backup?

Tags: applications, titanium-backup, disable-app

I just saw that I can "disable" an app in the app editing menu on my new HTC Droid DNA (stock Android 4.1 w/Sense).

The main effect I can see is that the app disappears from app drawer.

**How is this "disabling" different from Titanium Backup's "freezing"?** (as far as full effects)

Comment: Related but NOT duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29976/how-do-you-disable-system-apps-in-android-4-x-x-and-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they achieve the same thing. Not only the app would not be available in the app drawer but the app cannot be launched using [`am start`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) too. The only difference is that default mechanism allows you to disable specific pre-installed apps while Titanium Backup would allow you to disable any app.

For Android version like 4.2.1, when you disable a pre-installed app from Android "Settings", this line would show up in `/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml`:

```
<pkg name="PKG_NAME" enabled="3" />
```

For Android 4.4 or 5.x, it would be:

```
<pkg name="PKG_NAME" enabled="3" enabledCaller="com.android.settings" />
```

where `PKG_NAME` → [package name of an app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/96277), such as for Calculator it is `com.android.calculator2`.

However, when you disable aka freeze an app using Titanium Backup, the `enabledCaller` gets the value `shell:0`, i.e.:

```
<pkg name="PKG_NAME" enabled="3" enabledCaller="shell:0" />
```

- In both the cases, if the app is a pre-installed app then it would only show "Enable" option under Settings → Apps → *your_app*.
- If it is a user installed app then Android would not show "Enable" option but the app would still be labelled "Disabled".

  <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

  [image: IMG:]

---

## `pm` is different

`pm disable PKG_NAME` also disables an app but the app then wouldn't be visible even under Settings → Apps.

Also, when you disable an app using `pm disable` a different value for `enabled` is recorded.

For Android 4.2.1:

```
<pkg name="PKG_NAME" enabled="2" />
```

For Android 4.4 and 5.x:

```
<pkg name="PKG_NAME" enabled="2" enabledCaller="shell:0" />
```

You can disable **any app** using `pm` provided that you've root access.