# Enable Package Installer

Tags: apk, disable-app

I have rooted OnePlus 5t, I used Lucky Pacher to disable Package Installer and when I reboot my device I got boot loop... Is there something I can do beside factory rest? is there an option to enable it via recovery or fastboot mode?

I have OrangeFox recovery mode

This is the XML file `package-restrictions.xml`:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FThuUEt4pII_FBVpSUl7sjWoXLiq_zcG/view?usp=sharing
https://pastebin.com/XXE455pJ

Comment: Did you do anything beside disabling Package Installer when using Lucky Patcher? Did Lucky Patcher do anything to Package Installer app aside from simply disabling it? Look for the  package name  of Package Installer app inside `/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml`. Edit out the related lines or change `enabled=` to `enabled=1`. Reference: my own answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49580/96277)

Comment: I didn't do anything beside disabling Package Installer when using Lucky Patcher - Just disable. In OrangeFox recovery I go to > /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml, and then click on it >> Open as... >> Text File. I can't edit the file but I can see it. Its a very very long text... what line I need to check?

Comment: This is the XML file package-restrictions.xml: https://pastebin.com/XXE455pJ. and how can I edit this file?

Comment: Link to file in Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FThuUEt4pII_FBVpSUl7sjWoXLiq_zcG/view?usp=sharing. and how can I edit this file?

Comment: Open `adb shell` and execute these two commands: `busybox sed -i '/1570736/s/enabled="2"/enabled="1"/' /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml` and `grep 1570736 /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml`. Report the output. It should have `enabled="1"`. If it does, reboot the device and see if the boot loop still persists. Report your observation back here.

Comment: If boot loop **still persists**, reboot back into recovery, run `adb shell` and run this command: `busybox sed -i '/1570736/d' /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml`

Comment: /sbin/sh: busybox: not found. In the adb on the computer when phone is in Recovery mode --- When I am typing “adb shell” I got: “dumpling:/ # ”. Then when I’m typing “su” I got: “/sbin/sh: su: not found”. Same with “adb shell pm list packages” I got: “/sbin/sh: pm: not found”

Comment: Ah yes. Your recovery doesn't have busybox. That's okay. Just enter `adb shell`. A custom recovery always give you a shell with default root access, (that # means root), so you  don't need to run `su`. Just enter my commands without `busybox` word in them and report your findings.

Comment: WOW!!!!! my phone is working! ty!!! now it's keep giving me a message: `com.android.phone has stopped working` non stop! I can't use my phone... It's endless LOL what happened?

Comment: I don't know why it is giving you that error. Did you do anything with Lucky Patcher other than disabling Package Installer? You would want to use logcat to get the errors and figure them out.

Comment: What is logcat?

Comment: Search Google for logcat and how to use it.