# how to freeze/hibernate system apps in non-root android mobilephones

Tags: bloatware, system-apps

- is there any methods to freeze/hibernate `bloatwares` on android phones?
- using `samsung galaxy note 3`

Comment: What version of Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to simply go into Settings -> Apps -> All apps, select the pre-installed app and choose the "disable" option. Hit "OK", and the app will no longer exist on the home screen, will no longer run, and will essentially cease to exist on your device.

Take a look at [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29976/how-do-you-disable-system-apps-in-android-4-x-x-and-up?rq=1) question for more info.