# Disabled apps keep coming back

Tags: applications, uninstallation

I followed the instructions found in [this StackExchange post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29976/how-do-you-disable-system-apps-in-android-4-x-x-and-up) to disable the YouTube app on my phone.

Everything seemed to go well at first; the updates were uninstalled and the icon was hidden away to oblivion. However, a couple minutes later, I saw a notification that the YouTube app was being updated from the Google Play Store. Lo and behold, the app reinstalled itself and returned to its former place in my app drawer.

No matter how many times I try to disable the YouTube app, it just keeps coming back. Is there any way to permanently disable it?

I'm running Android 5.1.1 on an Xperia Z1 Compact.

Comment: Try to: disable YouTube; open it from the Play Store; disable it again. This did the trick for me (on a Samsung-flavoured Lollipop). Emptying Play Store's cache had no effect.

Comment: Same problem on Android 9.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Try using **Greenify** app to hibernate Youtube app (if you are a rooted user). Once hibernated, it won't come into picture unless explicitly opened.

You can also use **Titanium Backup** to freeze Youtube app, if u want to permanently disable it. You can unfreeze the app later anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try Force Stopping them, before disabling. It was frustrating for me too but it worked for all the default google apps that I didn't need.