# How do I uninstall a browser

Tags: settings, browser, hardware, uninstallation

Can I disable/ uninstall the browser that came with the phone without disabling another browser I have installed? How do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop applications and services from running?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/how-can-i-stop-applications-and-services-from-running)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable system apps in Android 4.x.x (and up)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29976/how-do-you-disable-system-apps-in-android-4-x-x-and-up)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot uninstall the browser bundled with the phone (unless you're rooted); you can though disable it, without affecting any other browser you installed.
How depends on the phone model and the os version you're running. On mine I would go into Settings -> Apps -> (app name) -> Disable.

Comment: I tried but I don't have the choice of :disable" just uninstall. Any suggestion?

Comment: What does "rooted: mean

Comment: Is there just a WAY TO HIDE THE ICON ON MY HOME SCREEN

Comment: @Tom if you have the option to uninstall, then uninstall it. Rooted means to gain root privileges in the meaning of a linux system [1]. Yes you can remove each icon of your home screen keeping them pressed, and then you will see the 'remove' icon (usually on top).
I recommend you google as there are plenty of links, and also I recommend you specify the phone model and os version while asking questions.

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android_OS)