# How do you move a contact in address book tied to an email to different one?

Tags: contacts

Have multiple accounts that I am logged in on my phone. Since the last one is my work Android assumes it is my default. I added a contact which was saved to the wrong address book and I need to move them is there a way to easily do that without having to delete and recreate them.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find an option to do it easily but here are some solutions:

You can export the contacts to your storage and import it to the right account.

You can also share the contact by email for instance and send it to the right account. Then just import it from your email.

[image]

**EDIT:** If you have set up a default application for handling contacts intents (for instance if another app such as outlook automatically imports the contacts), you will need to reset your intent associations. See [How can I manage Intent association with Apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2538/how-can-i-manage-intent-association-with-apps)

Last option, you can use the Contacts website (on your computer) which is in my opinion easier to use if you have multiple adjustments to make: https://www.google.com/contacts/

Comment: Sadly one is a gmail account and the other is outlook. When I import it quickly flashes the accounts option before automatically adding it to the outlook address book.

Comment: In that case, you will need to change your intent associations. See my edit.